# why signal triggered in wrong time?

Tags: python, django, model, django-signals

I'm creating a signal which creates a profile for the `user` considering the `group` they are in.
For example if they user is in `TEACHER` group the `teacher_profile` would be created for it.

The problem is that the signal triggered before the `group` of user has been set and gives me the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'`.

```
#views.py
def register_page(request):
    if request.POST:
        password = request.POST['password']
        repassword = request.POST['repassword']
        username = request.POST['username']
        GROUP = request.POST['group']
        if password == repassword:
            #creating user
            user = User.objects.create(is_superuser=False, username=username)
            user.groups.set([Group.objects.get(name=GROUP), ])
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            
            #authenticating user
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/esadra/user/dashboard/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'پسورد ها مطابقت ندارند')
```

```
#models.py

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_profile_creator(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.groups.first().name == 'TEACHER':
            profile = teacher.objects.create(user=instance)
        elif instance.groups.objects.first().name == 'Student':
            profile = student.objects.create(user=instance)
```

I have tried `m2m_changed` that made other problems for `set_password` , it made the user instance `None type` because it should be saved to trigger the `m2m_changed` signal.

Every answer would be appreciated.

Comment: M2Ms are saved after instances are saved, you will most probably face other issues with many to many relations even if you'll solve this one, an option might be to use both m2m_changed and post_save, but this way you'll be executing things multiple times

Comment: No other sulotion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to accomplish it straight away in the view

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.POST:
        password = request.POST['password']
        repassword = request.POST['repassword']
        username = request.POST['username']
        GROUP = request.POST['group']
        if password == repassword:
            #creating user
            group = Group.objects.get(name=GROUP)
            user = User.objects.create(is_superuser=False, username=username)
            user.groups.set([group, ])
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            if group.name == 'TEACHER':
                teacher.objects.create(user=user)
            elif group.name == 'Student':
                student.objects.create(user=user)
            
            #authenticating user
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/esadra/user/dashboard/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'پسورد ها مطابقت ندارند')
```

additionally if you want to make it more readable or so, just extract it into separate funcs etc.

Will that do the trick for you ?

Comment: Thanks for answer it works. but it was better to be able to use signals. due to the DRY stuff.